# UITableView in UITableViewCell won't scroll to bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` with a `UITableView` inside using a custom cell with a height of 77. I cannot scroll all the way though the UITableView, the last row is cut off.

I am using this code to create the frame for the table view.

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

_routeTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, screenWidth, screenHeight) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Here is a short [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pVG2ExNk9o&feature=youtu.be) showing my issue:

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can properly scroll through the routes?

It seems there is no space for cells upward, not just cutting off the last cell.

```
-(void)configureRouteTableView
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    _routeTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, screenWidth, screenHeight - 50) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    _routeTableView.delegate = self;
    _routeTableView.dataSource = self;
    _routeTableView.hidden = YES;
    _routeTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [_routeTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_routeTableView];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My personal experience

1) Make sure scroll content size a multiple of the uitableview cell size

2) Make sure your tableview's y-coordinate plus tableview's height does not exceed the screen.

For your case, I think it is number 2, that's causing your trouble. Since,

_routeTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, screenWidth, screenHeight) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

50+screenHeight, means some part of your tableview is off the screen. :)

Thanks to suggester for suggesting. I'm not sure why I can't make use of your editing.

Comment: The reason it is set at 50 is because if not the table view is on top of the stop title and distance labels.

Comment: then you should use
"CGRectMake(0, 50, screenWidth, screenHeight-50)". That extra 50 has passed the screen height. You just need to set it screenHeight-50. :)

Comment: I tried that and no cigar, upon further inspection its more of no scroll space upwards rather than cutting off the last row.

Comment: Where did you do the screenHeight-50?

Comment: sorry, was away. I believe it's because of the size of your cell. screenHeight + 50 wouldn't work, because you have to accommodate for cell size. :) Correct me if I'm wrong please. And take note about +90, make sure the lowest cell is not out of the screen border; make sure the bottom uitableviewcell is really the bottom one.

Answer (score 2):

As I see you have two options to fix this issue:

1) First adjust the frame of the UITableView:

`_routeTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, screenWidth, screenHeight - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];`

which means the height of the table view is the height of screen minus height of navigationbar and starts just after navigationbar on y-axis.

2) Give some height to your UITableView's footer. (not recommended)

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50.0f;
}`

Also please make sure that this delegate function returns actual cell height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return yourTableCellHeight;
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to fix the issue, the code I pasted was in reference to the sub tableview in the cell. It seems there is no 'space' above the table view to allow scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the frame line to:

```
_routeTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, screenWidth, 90) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing what you are trying to accomplish, well if it solves then it is great. Beside this i do not prefer hard coded values to a frame, try to do some calculations and get the values 50 and 90. So if this app goes to iPad or some other device, you don't have to put IF...ELSE... (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Please set tableview cell height in following method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    return height;//77

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use contentInsets of tableview. You could setup it in IB. But disable auto layout first.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using Autolayout constraints instead of letting iOS do the (wrong) thing:

If you use a Podfile, install [UIView+Autolayout](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout):

```
pod 'UIView+Autolayout'
```

include UIView-Autolayout.h

```
#import "UIView-Autolayout.h"
```

and use this in your viewDidLoad:

```
[tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[tableView pinToSuperviewEdges:JRTViewPinAllEdges inset:0.0];
```